# compare two files and get the output for the same lines

Tags: linux, bash

How can I get the following output using linux command by comparing two text files? Thanks.

file1:

```
site110
site120
```

file2(Updated):

```
domain1.com - site110
domain2.com - site111
domain3.com - site112
domain4.com - site113
domain5.com - site120
domain6.com - site1201
domain7.com - site1202
```

output:

```
domain1.com - site110
domain5.com - site120
```

If I use:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

the output will be:

```
domain1.com - site110
domain5.com - site120
domain6.com - site1201
domain7.com - site1202
```

which the last two lines are not what I want. Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to add "[SOLVED]", the system has its own indicators.

Comment: I can't make `grep -f` work here either, but if I add `-w` to the `grep` command it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [grep manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

Therefore:

```
grep -f file1 file2

domain1.com - site110
domain5.com - site120
```

Comment: I tried grep -f file1 file2 before, but it didn't work on my script. I thought it doesn't work. Now, I have fixed my script. Thank you.

Comment: This matches `site1201` here, but if I add `-w` to the `grep` command it works.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command.

```
comm -12 < (sort file1) < (sort file2)
```

This command is more accurate than `grep -f`.

Comment: Love this, thanks! Works well for directories too:    comm -12 <(ls -1 dir1/ | sort) <(ls -1 dir2/ | sort)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a kind of database join function.  Unix has a command for that: [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join).  In you case:

```
join -1 1 -2 3 -t " " -o 2.1,2.2,2.3 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [diff](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm)?

Comment: At first, I thought diff may solve my problem, but I don't know which option to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be `man paste` ? Some output processing can be needed.